# Medical Questions?

Tags: discussion

Is it OK to ask questions here like:

> [Something] happened to me; my doctor says it will heal by itself and that I don't need to do anything. I'm skeptical -- is there really nothing I need to do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Off-topic. Go see another doctor.